# How to add .txt to all files in a directory using terminal

Tags: bash, terminal

I have many files without file extention. Now I want to add `.txt` to all files. I tried the following but it gives an error, `mv: rename . to ..txt: Invalid argument`.

How can I achieve this?

```
find . -iname "*.*" -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "$0.txt"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're nearly there!

Just add `-type f` to only deal with *files*:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "$0.txt"' {} \;
```

If your `mv` handles the `-n` option, you might want to use it (that's the option to not overwrite existing files).

---

The error your having is because `.` is one of the first found by `found`, and your system complains (rightly) when you want to rename `.`! with the `-type f` you're sure this won't happen. Now if you wanted to act on everything inside your directory, you would, e.g., add `-mindepth 1` at the beginning of the `find` command (as `.` is considered depth 0).

---

It is not very clear in your question, but what if you want to add the extension `.txt` to all *files* that *don't have an extension*? (we'll agree that *to have an extension* means *to have a period in the name*). In this case, you'll use the negation of `-name '*.*'` as follows:

```
find . -type f \! -name '*.*' -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "$0.txt"' {} \;
```